# how to use makefile and what does "no such jobs " mean

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Hi I am trying to run makefile using %make but it tells me "no such jobs" I am not sure how makefile should be saved as but it is in the same directory as my other files that I am trying to run.

Comment: You should not use a percent sign before it; just run `make`.  Where did the percent sign come from?

Comment: Just in case your curious what a `%` means: Look for "job control" in your shell manual.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example of a simple Makefile using g++:

makefile:

```
all:
  g++ main.cpp anotherFile.cpp -o someBinaryOutput
```

Now all you have to do is call the `make` keyword to compile and the `./` to run i.e:

```
user@comp:path/to/directory$make
user@comp:path/to/directory$./someBinaryOutput
```